# Paypal express checkout in phonegap apps

Tags: cordova, paypal, google-checkout

Is there a way to use the paypal mobile express checkout library in a phonegap application without writing native code?

Answer (score 1):

Have a try at this Phonegap plugin: https://github.com/azicchetti/MECLPayPalPlugin

This and the Childbrowser plugin together should let you use the MECL Paypal library through javascript code only.